# Regression models that conform to functional groupings of features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, nonparametric, cart

For example, suppose we want to predict `y` with features `x1, x2, x3, x4`. If I specify

```
y = fA(x1, x2) * fB(x3) + fC(x4)
```

where each `f` is nonparametric (e.g. a decision tree), is there any model that can train a model based on this form specification?